# PHP combined static and non-static class vs 2 separate classes

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, static-methods, static-members

I have a PHP class for building HTML tags. Each HTML tag becomes of new instance. I have some utility methods needed within the class for handling certain functional stuff like escaping attributes and for configuring certain options that affect all instances. I'm declaring the utilities and `public static` and within the class I'm using `self::` to call the utility methods. Do you think it's better to keep all the methods in one class **or** to create a separate static class for the utilities and have it so the main class extends the static one (so that I can still call the methods with `self::`)? What is the best way to handle this type of situation? (in PHP 5.2 and up) The interface for the class is like this:

```
foo('div')->attr('id', 'example')->html('this is inner text')->get();

foo('img')->attr(array('src' => 'example.png', 'alt' => 'example'))->get();
```

Example of the underlying code:

```
public function attr($name, $value = '')
{
    if (is_scalar($name))
    {
        if (empty($name) && !is_int($name)) $this->attrs[] = $value; 
        else $this->attrs[$name] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ((array) $name as $k => $v)
        {
            $this->attr($k, $v);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

// handler (doesn't get called until it's time to get)
public static function attr_encode($name, $value = '')
{
    if (is_scalar($name))
    {
        if (is_int($name)) return self::attr_encode($value, '');
        $name = preg_replace(self::ATTR_NAME_INVALIDS, '', $name);
        if ('' === $name)  return '';
        if (1 === func_num_args() || '' === $value) return $name;

        $value = is_null($value) ? 'null' : ( !is_scalar($value) ? (
                 self::supports('ssv', $name) ? self::ssv_implode($value) : json_encode($value)) : (
                 is_bool($value) ? (true === $value ? 'true' : 'false') : self::esc_attr($value)));

         return $name . "='" . $value . "'";     // Use single quotes for compatibility with JSON.
    }

    // Non-scalar - treat $name as key/value map:
    $array = array();
    foreach ((array) $name as $attr_name => $attr_value)
    {
        self::push($array, true, self::attr_encode($attr_name, $attr_value));
    }
    return implode(' ', $array);
}
```

Comment: Placing all code in 1 class is not OOP. Can you show some code in which you are not sure what to do?

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo Example added. If the utilities are specific to the `Foo` class then don't they belong with the `Foo` class? How is that not OOP?

Comment: Static methods should only be used sparingly.  Excessive use of static is a code smell.  Just imagine that the word "static" is replaced with "global" and you ought to realise why.

Comment: _Each HTML tag becomes of new instance._ - If you mean what I think you mean, your functions should be returning `$this`, not creating a new instance.

Comment: @AndrewR They are—look in my example above.

Comment: @GordonM Why compare static to global?

Comment: I'd also love to get your guys' input on another PHP question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442668/php-methods-that-work-in-both-instantiated-and-static-contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic gives you some good info about how, when and when not to use static classes:

[When to use static vs instantiated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185605/when-to-use-static-vs-instantiated-classes)

Also.. You wrote:

> The interface for the class is like this:

Interfaces in PHP / OOP are something else. Interfaces force the programmer to use certain methods in classes.

Comment: I have no doubt that I need some static methods. What I'm trying to decide is whether it's better to include them in the main class or create a separate class that is purely static and extend the main class from that.

Comment: Create a seperate class that is purely static :-) In that case it's easier to use that static code elsewhere if needed

Comment: Got em' separated now and yea I think it's gonna be better. I have it so the non-static one extends the static one, so that I can use `self::` to call the utils from there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're building something similar to LINQ to XML classes: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html#example_1 or http://phphaml.sourceforge.net/

Perhaps theres some interface styles there you can adapt.

Comment: Cool - thanks - good to know about. What I'm doing is a bit simpler. I'll post the link when I have it Github.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building own PHP5 HMVC project where using on some library using STATIC with namespaces:

```
\Project\library\output::set_header_status(100);
```

But imagine your problem:

- I want add functions before calling some functions, or avoid as:

  ```
  $output = \Project\library\output->log(true, 'directory_log_of_header/');

  \Project\library\output::set_header_status(100);
  ```

So, there was problem. This examples don't work. Instead of this example function I will avoid this using STATIC, and use `$this` and calling a new instance.

If I need add some function, put some variables and prepare for calling function It should be using `non-static` using instance.

---

I'm using STATIC method only for directly calling function without previous prepare function, set variables, or for counters, or setting a variable which really needs using static. For example it can be for calling GET/POST data or directly example calling CLEARING CACHE (example remove cache from files directly without non-static).

- If I'm using only static, I don't know how many instances are calling for instances, if you have in class where calling another instances needs than better solution is really using `non-static`.

  People who builds projects using STATIC method you can't properly analyze where are static methods/class/function called. This would be harder for maintenance and development for the future business.

  Use STATIC only if functions offers small tasks, directly grabbing a data which didn't change often, or for small tasks as variables, dummy data (example: versions, checking, counters, checkers), for HASH algoritms and similar.